# Difference between $(document).ready and writing open jQuery statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between writing code with and without `$(document).ready`?

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        //Code
    });
});
```

And:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    //Code
});
```

And :

```
 <input id="button" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="hidedropdown()" />

    function hidedropdown() {
        //Code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, the code isn't executed until the DOM is ready.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code.

If you execute the second code in a `script` element located at the start of your HTML or in the header, the `button` elements wouldn't be found and no event handler would be bound. Using `.ready` fixes that.

Putting your scripts at the bottom of the page (adjacent to `</body>`) also solves this problem for the same reason - by the time the script is parsed, the HTML will be converted to the DOM and you can traverse it.

Comment: side note for OP: ready doesn't wait for images to download or iframe data.